# Execution of JAR on Azure App Service on timely manner

Tags: azure, jar, azure-web-app-service

I have one JAR which gets some data from Database and generates one CSV file. I have deployed this JAR on Azure App Service where it generates the CSV file every minute. So we need to keep the App Service in Stop state to avoid creation of CSV every minute. Whenever we require the CSV we start the App Service and then stop it again after generation of it.

I'm identifying the alternate way to avoid generating the CSV file every minute. Is there any functionality in Azure App Service using which we can run the deployed JAR at specific time only.
OR Is there any other resource on Azure where we can deploy JAR and execute it on timely manner. Can we make use of LogicApp or any other functionality to achieve this scenario.

Comment: As per my understanding and based on your requirement using azure web app is not an suitable option here. I would suggest you use azure functions [Create a Java function using Visual Studio Code - Azure Functions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-java) and a time trigger to run that executable/jar file.

Comment: Here is an idea you can refer to, you can start the App Service through the PowerShell command "[Start-AzWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/start-azwebapp?view=azps-9.1.0)" before generating the CSV file, and stop the App Service through the "[Stop-AzWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/stop-azwebapp?view=azps-9.1.0)" command after the CSV file is generated. You can use DevOps Scheduled triggers to control when the pipeline runs.

Comment: But I was thinking to use other Azure Resource or different tool for this requirement. As this Azure App Service only contains one JAR which generates CSV every second. So instead of deploying JAR to Azure App Service, is there any other option on Azure I can try for this requirement ?

Comment: @AjitMedhekar As I have mentioned earlier in my above comment you can use Azure Functions service which supports Java runtime, and you trigger the job based on the CORN expression using timer trigger function in it.